# Remove DOM element from variable with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Please help me solve this:

I have got this:

```
var text='<li id="job1">Job 1</li>'+
         '<li id="job2">Job 2</li>'+
         '<li id="job3">Job 3</li>';
```

and I want to remove one element, something like this:

```
$("#job2",$(text)).remove();
```

this doesnt work. Is there a way how to do it? thanks.

**EDIT:**
And I want to save result back to text:

```
 text='<li id="job1">Job 1</li><li id="job3">Job 3</li>';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your var `text` is just a variable that's holding a **string**

`<li id="job1">Job 1</li><li id="job2">Job 2</li><li id="job3">Job 3</li>`

And string is not an object so you cannot use `.remove()`

---

But once you do for eg:

`$('#someElement').append(text);`

than you can simply do:

`$('#job2').remove();`

and retrieve your new string using:

```
text = $('#someElement').html(); // '<li id="job1">Job 1</li><li id="job3">Job 3</li>'
```

Comment: Owwww yeah. Thanks a lot I need this.

Comment: But once you wrap it in `$()` it will become jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this...

*Update **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XN2uC/2/)**
My first version of code `$(text).find("#job2").remove();` did't worked in jsfiddle, but when I've added `<ul></ul>` to the code its worked like charm. I've no idea why did't worked with first instance without `ul` And I do not see any occasion where `li` will come without `ul` So please try like this.

```
var text='<ul><li id="job1">Job 1</li>'+
         '<li id="job2">Job 2</li>'+
         '<li id="job3">Job 3</li></ul>';

$text = $(text);
// console.log($text);
$text.find("li#job2").remove();
// console.log($text.find("li#job2"));
$('div').append($text);​
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to remove 'job2' from text

```
$(text).find("#job2").remove();
```

Comment: And how to save the result back to the variable?

Comment: +1 for simplicity. @petkopalko, The variable `text` will contain the new (amended) string.